# Can a changeset hold back other changesets?

Tags: tfs

I had a changeset, say #1000 that was not merged from Dev > Test.  Once this changeset was merged, I saw a list of changesets that previously were not available suddenly display when I perform another merge operation.

Why does this happen?

Comment: We aren't allowed to ask TFS questions on SO?

Comment: A comment explaining why this was closed would be helpful.

Comment: I've had this exact scenario happen between related branches (e.g. Parent > Child)! Old changesets (like 3-4 years old) would all of a sudden be in the merge candidate list. I would like to see the question answered.

Comment: Note this happened again after a major refactoring. Some changesets that I KNOW got promoted (major bugs that blow our app to hades) re-appeared when I attempted a changeset merge from DEV to TEST. Where Dev had a major refactor and TEST did not. There's something goofy about how TFS calculates changesets to merge.